# Are latches and flip flops the only sequential circuits with memory?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, logic-gates, latch

I understand that any sequential circuit can be generalised as a combinational circuit with feedback. Also, latches and flip flops are sequential circuits that have the memory property( ie they can store one bit of data). My doubt is regarding the memory property of latches and flip flop, isn't the memory property specific only to latches and flip flop and not any other sequential circuit. Isn't the memory property in latches and flip flop due to the cross coupled connection of NAND/NOR gates and also due to the fact that when enable/clock signal is not applied then latch/flip flop holds the previous output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a question being asked.  And what resembles a question is questionable.

> Also, latches and flip flops are sequential circuits that have the
>   memory property

They are not sequential circuit in themselves, they are used in non-sequential circuits as well.

> isn't the memory property specific only to latches and flip flop and
>   not any other sequential circuit.

Any type of memory can be used in a state machine, it depends on your resources.  When designing a custom IC you have more choices than when using TTL logic.   Again, not sequential circuits.

> Isn't the memory property in latches and flip flop due to the cross
>   coupled connection of NAND/NOR gates

As are all logic circuits.

> and also due to the fact that when enable/clock signal is not applied then latch/flip flop holds the previous output.

That's kinda how most memory devices work, but an irrelevant fact.

Answer (score 1):

Going by this and your other recent question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304265/what-is-state-in-a-sequential-circuit) you seem to be looking for a clear non-overlapping definitions for various terms used for describing circuits. Don't waste your time, while the terms are defined the edges are somewhat fuzzy and there is a lot of overlap.

By their nature logic gates are sequential. All circuits are made up of logic gates. This does not mean that all circuits are purely sequential however they will all contain sequential elements.

A latch or a flipflop are specific types of circuit that happens to have memory. They achieve this by using feedback, the signal from one gate is connected to an earlier gate in the sequence. Feedback by it's nature is not sequential even though all of the logic gates used to create it are.
This does not mean that all circuits with feedback have memory or don't act as if they were purely sequential.
It may or may not mean that all circuits with memory have feedback (I can't think of any that don't but I could easily be wrong).